# Populating a dropdown based on the value selected in another dropdown

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, jstl

I have two dropdowns defined in a modal that need to be filled and send a request to the spring controller. The particular dropdowns are populated by a list binded in spring modelAttributes. And the second dropdown should be changed according to the selection in the first one.

model attribute :

```
model.addAttribute("configJson", configs);
```

the view :

```
     <div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="signup_type_select">Sign Up Type</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="signup_type_select"
                                        onchange="toggleAdditionalInfoInput('#signup_type_select')"
                                        placeholder="name" name="type">
                                    <c:forEach items="${configJson.getLeads()}" var="option">
                                        <option value="${option.getName()}">${option.getName()}</option>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <c:forEach items="${configJson.getLeads()}" var="values" varStatus="count">


                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${values.getAcceptedValue().size() eq 0}">
                                        <div class="form-group hidden" id="signup_${count.index}_div">
                                            <label for="${values.getName()}">Event1</label>
                                            <input required type="text" disabled="disabled" class="form-control"
                                                   id="signup_${count.index}_input"
                                                   placeholder="event" name="event">
                                        </div>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:otherwise>
                                        <c:choose>
                                            <c:when test="${count.index eq 0}">
                                                <div class="form-group" id="signup_${count.index}_div">
                                                    <label for="${values.getName()}">Event2</label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" id="signup_${count.index}_input"
                                                            placeholder="value" name="value">
                                                        <c:forEach items="${values.getAcceptedValue()}"
                                                                   var="context">
                                                            <option>${context}</option>
                                                        </c:forEach>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </c:when>
                                            <c:otherwise>
                                                <div class="form-group hidden" id="signup_${count.index}_div">
                                                    <label for="${values.getName()}">Event3</label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" disabled="disabled"
                                                            id="signup_${count.index}_input"
                                                            placeholder="value" name="value">
                                                        <c:forEach items="${values.getAcceptedValue()}"
                                                                   var="context">
                                                            <option>${context}</option>
                                                        </c:forEach>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </c:otherwise>
                                        </c:choose>
                                    </c:otherwise>
                                </c:choose>
                            </c:forEach>

                        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleAdditionalInfoInput(id){
var divId = $(id).val();
var inputid = id;
console.log(id)
inputid = id.replace('select','');
console.log(id)
var optionList = $(id+' > option').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();


for(var i =0;i<optionList.length;i++){
    if(optionList[i] === divId){
        console.log(inputid+"_"+i+"_div")
        $(inputid+i+"_div").removeClass("hidden")
        $(inputid+i+"_input").removeAttr("disabled")
    }else{
        $(inputid+i+"_div").addClass("hidden")
        $(inputid+i+"_input").attr("disabled","disabled")
      }
   }

}
 </script>
```

the model class that binds the values to the attribute:

```
public class WebsiteContentLeadInfoJsonHelper {

private List<AdditionalInformationContext> leads ;

public List<AdditionalInformationContext> getLeads() {
    return leads;
}

public void setLeads(List<AdditionalInformationContext> leads) {
    this.leads = leads;
  }
}
```

AdditionalInformationContext class :

```
public class AdditionalInformationContext {
String name;
List<String> acceptedValue;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<String> getAcceptedValue() {
    return acceptedValue;
}

public void setAcceptedValue(List<String> acceptedValue) {
    this.acceptedValue = acceptedValue;
  }
}
```

the json values that are read and binded to the model class:

```
{  
 "leads":[  
  {  
     "name":"webinars",
     "acceptedValue":[  
        "how-to-save-money-with-clover",
        "Elo-Star-ddd"
     ]
  },
  {  
     "name":"events",
     "acceptedValue":[  
        "NRA-2016",
        "Money2020-2018"
     ]
   }
 ]
```

}

now the issue is the second dropdown is not selected according to the selection of the first one. How can I solve this? (only "how-to-save-money-with-clover","Elo-Star-ddd" are shown.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something simple using jQuery.

First, catch the event of first dropdown being selected, using an event handler.

```
$( "#firstDropdownId" ).change(function() {
  populateSecondDropdown();
});
```

After that, clear any previous options, then populate it accordingly and refresh it.

```
function populateSecondDropdonw(){  
  $('#secondDropdownId').children().remove();
  $.each(values.getAcceptedValue(), function(val, text) {
     $('#secondDropdownId').append($('<option></option>').val(text).html(text));
  });
  $('#secondDropdownId').focus();
}
```

For the clearing and refreshing methods would vary, i.e. if you are using select2 you would clear the select using `$('#sel').select2('data', null);` and refresh it using  `$('#secondDropdownId').trigger('change');`

Comment: thanks for the answer. I set a listener and now the value is removed once the selection is changed in the first dropdown. But iwant to set the event values according to the selection. The values are in the JSTL element ${configJson.getLeads().getAcceptedValue()}. As an example (when the selection is webinar -> how-to-save-money-with-clover,Elo-Star-Apptizer) and (for event -> NRA-2016,Money2020-2018) should be displayed. How to pass these values according to the selection?

Comment: The question is if you got all the possible options for the second dropdown in the first place or if you need to make a separate ajax call right after the selection in the first dropdown to get the appropriate values for the second.